# 3d-plotting surface 2x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2 = 6

Tags: matlab, octave

I was trying to plot the above surface in octave/matlab and ran into the this problem. 
My code is as follows:

```
x = linspace(-sqrt(3),sqrt(3),1000);
y = linspace(-sqrt(2),sqrt(2),1000);
z = sqrt(6-2*x.^2-3*y.^2);
surf(x,y,z)
```

I got the error:

```
error: mesh: X, Y, Z arguments must be real.
```

I understand this was because some `(x,y)`s would result in negative `6-2*x.^2-3*y.*2`, but I don't know how to tackle this because I can't trim either part of `x` or `y`. Any one can help? Thanks

Comment: Just a minor typo: I think you meant `3*y.^2` instead of `3*y.*2`.

Comment: You are right. I did mean 3*y.^2

Comment: you haven't properly defined branch cuts for  x y

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you want to do with the non-real values of `z`.
One thing you could do is to set all these values to zero or `NaN` (as per @hbaderts' comment):

```
z = sqrt(6-2*x.^2-3*y.^2);
z( imag(z)~=0 ) = NaN;
```

One more thing though: your code might have a problem because `z` is a length-`1000` vector, and you want it to be a `1000x1000` matrix. You should use `meshgrid()` on `x` and `y` to get two-dimensional matrices everywhere:

```
x = linspace(-sqrt(3),sqrt(3),1000);
y = linspace(-sqrt(2),sqrt(2),1000);
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = sqrt(6-2*xx.^2-3*yy.^2);
z( imag(z)~=0 ) = NaN;
surf(xx,yy,z,'edgecolor','none')
```

(thanks @LuisMendo for the `'edgecolor','none'` suggestion for better visualization.)

Running the above piece of code on octave gives this plot:
[image: 3-D plot that ignores non-real values.]

Comment: I was about to suggest setting these to `NaN` - that way they aren't displayed in the plot at all...

Comment: I fixed your not equals symbol.  It's `~=` in MATLAB and not `!=` as we expect in most programming languages (C, Java, Python, etc.).  Other than that, your tackle of the problem is the correct approach.

Comment: @rayryeng `!=` is perfectly valid in octave (which is one of the tags in the question), but I guess `~=` works for both matlab and octave so that's fine, thanks.

Comment: @jadhachem - I didn't see the Octave tag oops.  In that case, better to leave `~=` anyway so that it's good for both platforms... and you brought up that point anyway.  Take care!

Comment: `surf(xx,yy,z,'edgecolor','none')` may provide better visualization

Comment: I'm still not sure how to implement this.. and I ran into a similar problem today again. Could you explain to me what I should do to plot f(x,y) = sqrt(R^2 - x^2 - y^2)? Many thanks!

Comment: @MikeChen I'm not sure what you mean.. Have you tried the code I provided? Where did it go wrong?